# Positioning labels in Android menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to position labels in menu like on following drafts. It should behave like standard android menu - with `showAsAction="ifRoom"`. Everything I want is positioning labels under icon when item is in actionbar and positioning labels next to icon, when in dropdown menu.

So far I tried multiple menus definitions - with separating resources into *-land and *-port, searching android-arsenal, but without any luck. Is it possible to do that with 'official' android menu implementation or is there any 3rd party library for that? Writing my own implementation is the last resort.

[image: Some items in actionbar, some in dropdown]

Comment: Afaik, there is no simple setting to change the icon and its label from a horizontal to vertical appearance. However, you can fully customise the appearance of any menu item using [*action views* and *action providers*](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/appbar/action-views.html). Alternatively, if you're using a `Toolbar`, you could add those items as regular views, but then you don't get the smarts around `showAsAction="ifRoom"` of course.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that may be way too, I'll dig into it. While reading it I've been wondering if there is a way to figure out if certain item is expanded (visible on toolbar), or nested inside overflow menu? In that case I can hide that item and display customized view with label under icon.